# Find similar or "like" text and replace it with other in excel

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how i can find similar descriptions in excel and  replace them with 1 other description is there a wild card?

i am. trying to make a pivot chart with a list of  transactions and their descriptions and i want to group all my ATM withdrwls but i cant. On the pivot chart they appear as ATM Withdrwal-REF-1234 and each of these "withdrwls" have different reference and as a result they show up as individual items on the chart...how can i group say all my ATM withdrwals as 1 ATM Withrdawl item so that it shows a  1 atm withdrwl item on my pivot chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered making two fields-- one that captures the ATM Withdrwal portion of the string and one that captures the rest?  It would effectively be some sort of "category" field.

It should be a fairly simple thing to do with the macro capability in excel.